# Import ndjson into elasticsearch 7.2 by command line

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have a ndjson file `data.json` like:

```
{"index":"products"}
{"title": "item1", "price": 1}
{"index":"products"}
{"title": "item2", "price": 2}
{"index":"products"}
{"title": "item3", "price": 3}
{"index":"products"}
{"title": "item4", "price": 4}
...etc
```

I want to insert it into elasticSearch 7.2 and I use `curl`

```
curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/products/_bulk -H 'Content-Type:application/x-ndjson' --data-binary @data.json
```

but the callback error is:

```
{
"error":{
"root_cause":[{
"type":"illegal_argument_exception",
"reason":"Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [VALUE_STRING]"
}],
"type":"illegal_argument_exception",
"reason":"Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [VALUE_STRING]"
},
"status":400
}
```

My OS is MacOS Mojave 10.14.5

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Missing `"` around `price` property.

Comment: but `price` is integer property

Comment: Yes, but property name itself needs to be wrapped, `price` -> `"price"` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first (action/metadata) line for each document needs to be a bit differemt. Your `data.json` file should look like this:

```
{"index": {"_index": "products"}}
{"title": "item1", "price": 1}
{"index": {"_index": "products"}}
{"title": "item2", "price": 2}
{"index": {"_index": "products"}}
{"title": "item3", "price": 3}
{"index": {"_index": "products"}}
{"title": "item4", "price": 4}
```